# Nginx testing domains in localhost point to same root folder

Tags: wordpress, nginx

In trying test server config in localhost with fake domains but all show the same nginx html example.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name  test.localhost www.test.localhost;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

and the other config is there

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080 ;

    root /var/www/website;
    index index.php;

    server_name  website.localhost www.website.localhost;

    location / {

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht { 
        deny all;
    }
}
```

the second config is an simple wordpress setup, i can enter with normally using the usual localhost:8080 but if i try to enter with the domains all both show the first config content.

I really don't know the reason why it happens, I'm not an expert in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;` inside your location directive?

Comment: the same problem